# What optimization method should I use here?

Tags: optimization

Suppose that we have the following (unconstrained) optimization problem:

$$
\min_{\mathbf{w},b} \frac{1}{2}\Arrowvert\mathbf{w}\Arrowvert^2 + C\sum_{i=1}^{l}g_i(\mathbf{w},b),
$$

where $\mathbf{w}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$. Moreover, for $i=1,\dots,l$, the functions $g_i: \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are differentiable and their partial derivatives with respect to $\mathbf{w}$, $b$ are known.

Which optimization methods should I use for that end? Is there a specially appropriate technique for the specific objective function?

Any useful comment/advice will be fully appreciated!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If also the second derivatives of the $g_i$ are known, you may want to use a (globalized) Newton method. Otherwise, a quasi-Newton method is a good choice.

Comment: thanks @gerw! But what I have found so far concerns the case of optimizing with respect to one variable, say $\mathbf{x}$ (in our case $\mathbf{w}$). Then, what happens when I want to have a joint optimization; with respect both to $\mathbf{w}$ **and** $b$?

Comment: Most literature on optimization deals with the minimization w.r.t. vectors. And $(w,b) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is indeed a vector.

Comment: thanks. Yeah, that's makes sense... I was looking for something more "explaining", which might include some equations, but ok, I'll try to find out what's going on! Thanks again! If you want to contribute with some eqs, it'll be welcome too!